# Is Java Media Components finally going to be implemented in Java 7?

Tags: java, release, media

A few months ago I read about a native media library being implemented in Java 7 ([link here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2007/05/24/media-frenzy)). Since then I've been searching for more information, but I didn't find anywhere if it's finally going to be included or not. Does anybody have more information about this? 
Thanks in advance.